# Split comma separated strings 5

Tags: c#, windows, datagridview, textbox

I have 5 values in datagridview column with comma like
`abc,xyz,asdf,qwer,mni`

how to split into string and display in textbox

```
abc
xyz
asdf
qwer
mni
```

Comment: So, in total, three questions: How do I get data from a DataGridView column (did you mean cell)? How to I set the text in a TextBox? How do I replace the commas in a string? No code, very little effort shown... Winforms?

Comment: @Brain: For displaying it in 5 different textboxes, you can use `Split()`. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need Split here, Just replace the comma in the string, [string.Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
str = str.Replace(",", " ");
```

**Edit**

```
string []arr = str.Split('c');
txt1.Text = arr[0];
txt2.Text = arr[1];
txt3.Text = arr[2];
txt4.Text = arr[3];
txt5.Text = arr[4];
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `.Replace(",", " ");`?

Comment: Thanks @npinti, already updated

Comment: I have 5 textboxes to display these 5 strings

Comment: yes it is . I was finding @Adil

Answer (score 0):

First replace comma with space:

```
str = str.Replace(',', '');
```

Then add it back to textbox:

```
textbox.Text = str;
```

Answer (score 0):

OP Says, he has 5 textboxes to display the words. So you can use `String.Split()`;

Example:

```
string str="abc,xyz,asdf,qwer,mni";

textbox1.Text = str.Split(',')[0];
textbox2.Text = str.Split(',')[1];
textbox3.Text = str.Split(',')[2];
textbox4.Text = str.Split(',')[3];
textbox5.Text = str.Split(',')[4];
```

**OR**

You can use an array:

```
string[] strarray = str.Split(',');
textbox1.Text = strarray[0];
textbox2.Text = strarray[1];
textbox3.Text = strarray[2];
textbox4.Text = strarray[3];
textbox5.Text = strarray[4];
```